# Converting simple Sql query to Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

Im working on my school project and im new in writing LINQ query's so its hard for me to convert this SQL query to LINQ. I have problem with writing linq query for top 10 best selling products. I have table for Products and table for Selling item.

[image]

My SQL query works good.
[image]

I tried with this:

```
  List<Proizvodi> proizvodi = db.Proizvodi.
            OrderByDescending(x => db.IzlazStavke.Where(y => y.ProizvodID == x.ProizvodID).
            Sum(t => t.Cijena)).Take(10).ToList();
```

But result is not good, any help please.

Comment: "_But result is not good_" - what exactly?

Comment: I got 10 products in list but not top 10 best selling products.

Comment: Why are you so surprised? In SQL query you get a sum of _IzlazStavke.Kolicina_ and in Linq query you get _Proizvodi.Cijena_.

Comment: You're right mate. I spent hours, now it's working good. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try something like this:

```
List<Proizvodi> proizvodi = db.Proizvodi
        .OrderByDescending(x => db.IzlazStavke
             .Where(y => y.ProizvodID == x.ProizvodID)
             .GroupBy(a=>a.ProizvodID)
             .Select(grp=>grp.Sum(z=>z.Kolicina))
        .Take(10)
        .ToList();
```